# import function from .so

Tags: c++, boost, dllimport

I need to import a function from a Linux .so library with boost.dll library. My code is like this:

```
namespace n1 {
    namespace n2 {
        struct st {
            std::string n;
            int m;
        }
    }
}

void foo(std::string const&, n1::n2::st& attr) {
    /*some implementation*/
}
```

Here I try to import the function `foo()`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    boost::filesystem::path path("some path");
    boost::dll::experimental::smart_library lib(path);
    auto f2 = lib.get_function<void(std::string const&, n1::n2::st&)>(path, "n1::n2::foo");  //<<----here runtime error
    f2( std::string(), st{});
}
```

but I get this runtime error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
>     what():  boost::dll::shared_library::get() failed (dlerror system message: /path_to_my_library.so: undefined symbol: n1::n2::foo): Illegal seek

Comment: Well? Did you include a header into the translation unit where `main()` is defined, or otherwise let the compiler know that `st` is declared within those namespaces? You seem to be mixing up importing symbols from DLLs versus compiling code that uses those symbols and their dependencies. Even if you can import a function from a DLL, that alone doesn't automatically get you declarations of all symbols it depends on.

Comment: @underscore_d, i must compile with -I(path to include) and include header file which contain implementation st?

Comment: If you refer to some symbol like `st`, the translation unit that's referring to it needs to know about it, through having a declaration available. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @underscore_d, thanks

Comment: @underscore_d, but std::terminated occured in dll::import

Comment: Then you have a different question and need to [edit] this one with a proper description of it, or post a new one.

Comment: @underscore_d, up

Comment: From the posted code I see that n1::n2::st is a type, while you can import instances from the dll (normally function pointers but also variables). From the problem description I get the impression that you expect to import a type, but that's not the case.

Comment: @marom, st it's struct who implement before BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT

Comment: It looks like you’re trying to import `n1::n2::foo`, but `foo` isn’t in `n1::n2` but instead in global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `n1::n2::foo` is not a C-compatible export name, I'd suggest you need either to use the mangled name, or use [`mangled_import`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_dll/mangled_import.html)

> Caution: This feature is experimental

On my compiler

```
foo(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, n1::n2::st&)
```

mangles to

```
_Z3fooRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERN2n12n22stE
```

On the topic of also importing the struct, see [Class Imports](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_dll/mangled_import.html#boost_dll.mangled_import.class_import)

### UPDATE

A working sample based on the manual mangling approach:

1. #### shared.cpp

   ```
   #include "shared.h"
   #include <iostream>

   void foo(std::string const& msg, n1::n2::st& attr) {
       std::cout << msg << " from " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " (" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ")\n";
       std::cout << "attr.m = " << attr.m << "\n";
       std::cout << "attr.n = " << attr.n << "\n";
   }
   ```
2. #### shared.h

   ```
   #include <string>
   namespace n1 { namespace n2 { struct st { std::string n; int m; }; } }
   ```
3. #### main.cpp

   ```
   #include <boost/dll.hpp>
   #include <boost/dll/smart_library.hpp>
   #include <boost/dll/import_mangled.hpp>
   #include <boost/exception/diagnostic_information.hpp>
   #include <iostream>

   #include "shared.h"

   int main() {
       boost::filesystem::path path("./libshared.so");
       try {
           boost::dll::experimental::smart_library lib(path);
           //auto f1 = boost::dll::experimental::import_mangled<void(std::string const&, n1::n2::st&)>(path, "foo");
           auto f1 = boost::dll::import<void(std::string const&, n1::n2::st&)>(path, "_Z3fooRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERN2n12n22stE");

           n1::n2::st arg { "world", 42 };
           f1("hello", arg);

       } catch(boost::exception const& e) {
           std::cout << boost::diagnostic_information(e, true) << '\n';
       }
   }
   ```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87fa84a2bf919fcb)**

Compiled with:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -shared -fPIC shared.cpp -o libshared.so
g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp -ldl -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

Show the mangled names with

```
nm libshared.so
```

Run the demo with

```
./a.out
```

Prints

```
hello from shared.cpp:5 (void foo(const string&, n1::n2::st&))
attr.m = 42
attr.n = world
```

Comment: with experimental::import_mangling runtine similar error... pls, can you write example?

Comment: Ah. So, you got an _identical_ error, not just a "similar" one?

Comment: @underscore_d, runtime error: "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >' what(): boost::dll::shared_library::get() failed (dlerror system message: /path_to_my_library.so: undefined symbol: n1::n2::foo): Illegal seek"

Comment: @xperious I added a working sample [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87fa84a2bf919fcb) using manual mangling. The experimental `import_mangled` did not work for me yet. Perhaps I'm using it wrong :)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @sehe, i mean with boost::dll::experimental::import_mangled<void(std::string const&, n1::n2::st&)>(path, "foo");   runtime_error occured(

Comment: Yes. I don't know what causes that, but it's experimental for a reaon, I guess.

Comment: @sehe, sorry, can you show how use function foo without dll import? if it possible in principle...

Comment: Sure. Just link it dynamically?

Comment: @sehe, i declare function foo in main.cpp... It solved all problems

Comment: Wow. So, why were you using Boost Dll before?

Comment: @sehe, i didn't understand how call function from dll if she no declare(sorry for my english)

Comment: "if she no declare" - you did declare it now. Why were you using a library with [a very specific use case](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_dll.html#boost_dll.introduction)? Didn't you need that functionality?